# RouteValues without using Query String?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have a form generated through Razor:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveProfile", "Settings", new { AccountID = Model.AccountID },
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
```

The RouteValues object, `new { AccountID = Model.AccountID }` gets shoved into the Query String, even though I don't specify to do so anywhere in my project.

How can I pass these values to my controller action without letting them show up in the URL?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC model-binding will recognize values passed by the query-string *or* the form (post) variables.

So you could include hidden inputs in the form with the var names as the `name` attributes and the values as the `value` attributes:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountID)
```